# Remap string values to new labels with pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Using Python, how might I take a Pandas dataframe column with values and replace them with a new sequence of values, allowing for duplicates and order. For example consider the following values:

```
56-34567 
56-25767 
56-24777 
56-23987 
56-23987 
56-23987 
56-34567
```

I would need to create something like:

```
ID_1 
ID_2 
ID_3 
ID_4 
ID_4 
ID_4 
ID_1
```

I need to account for multiple values. In my example 56-34567 (ID_1) occurs twice and 56-23987 (ID_4) occurs three times. The list of new values needs to reflect this in the correct order. Thank you, any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `groupby` and `ngroup` to get unique IDs for each current ID. You can then concatenate your prefix (a few ways to do this).

```
df

        col
0  56-34567
1  56-25767
2  56-24777
3  56-23987
4  56-23987
5  56-23987
6  56-34567
```

```
# df.groupby('col', sort=False).ngroup().add(1).astype(str).radd('ID_')
df.groupby('col', sort=False).ngroup().add(1).map('ID_{}'.format)

0    ID_1
1    ID_2
2    ID_3
3    ID_4
4    ID_4
5    ID_4
6    ID_1
dtype: object
```

Where `ngroup` returns,

```
df.groupby('col', sort=False).ngroup()

0    0
1    1
2    2
3    3
4    3
5    3
6    0
dtype: int64
```

The `sort=False` call is important here, because we want the output ordering to be identical to the input.

---

More options, cannot guarantee the same ordering however. One method is using `pd.factorize`:

```
np.char.add('ID_', (pd.factorize(df['col'])[0] + 1).astype(str))
# array(['ID_1', 'ID_2', 'ID_3', 'ID_4', 'ID_4', 'ID_4', 'ID_1'],
#      dtype='<U24')
```

An array is returned, you can then assign the result back,

```
df.assign(col=np.char.add('ID_', (pd.factorize(df['col'])[0] + 1).astype(str)))

    col
0  ID_1
1  ID_2
2  ID_3
3  ID_4
4  ID_4
5  ID_4
6  ID_1
```

Comment: ...you're a wizard. Thank you very much!